# Making an app only available to my customers

Tags: ios, login-control

I have a physical educational product which I sell in several countries, including Japan and China. 
The Chinese market is a huge opportunity, but complicated by potential piracy / counterfeiting issues. My product has a companion app - which I only want to make available to customers who have brought my physical product, and enter the app unlock code included with purchase. Customers that haven't purchased my product can buy a similar (non free) version of this app - in other words, this app adds value to the physical product, and helps counter piracy.

I got all the coding for the above done, then submitted the app to the app store, but it was rejected as my app unlocks content via other means than the app store.

Is there a work around for this, or a way to set up the app so that it is acceptable to apple? The custom b2b seems clunky and difficult to determine whether it will work - at least as far as I've been able to make sense of it.

Thanks in advance,
Leon

Comment: Does your app provide all functionalities independent from your physical product?

Comment: the app does provide some functionality beyond what is available in the physical product. - i.e. the physical product is an educational card game for language learning, and the app adds a voice to the cards so players can work on pronunciation. The two products compliment each other, and individually have value.

Comment: I was able to get this up and running on the ios store, though not without some troubles. It seems that it's a bit of a grey area as on one hand, apple terms say unlock functionality must be via IAP. On the other, there are a bunch of complimentary apps that are essentially unlocked through providing some sort of code provided when you buy goods. Apple let me through once I removed functionality before login, and changed the word unlock to password. It feels like sailing a little close to the wind, so not sure it's something I'd recommend.